# Jquery sortable is not working with touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created a simple jquery application, which supports `sortable` interaction. But this application does not work properly on mobile device with a touch screen. See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmyy/61/)

```
var divL;
var word = "lorem ipsum";
$(function(){
    var parsed = word.split("");;
    var x = $("#sortable");
    for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        $('<li></li>').attr('class','item').attr('id',i).html(parsed[i]).appendTo(x);   
    }
});
$(function() {
    x = $( '#sortable' )        
    x.sortable({
        placeholder:"itemPlaceHolder",
        cursor:"move",          
    });
    x.disableSelection();       
  });
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: sounds annoying, whats your question?

Comment: i dont know, maybe there is some kind of method that is making objects touchable ... i dont know .. that is why iam asking

Comment: Not working on my 3310 either :-D

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need touch support (jQuery UI does not have it). Check out the jQuery UI Touch Punch at http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Sadly touchpunch don't seems to be working anymore. I've tried everything to get it running but no success. Tried it on different browsers within IOS and Android.